# how to build a record with multiple references with has many association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 models named `Article`, `User`, `Comment`

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Now, if I want to build a comment for an article, I can use

```
@comment = @article.comments.build(comment_params)
```

This will add `article_id` to the `comment` object.

Now, if I want to add the `user_id` to `object`, I can add in the following way

```
@comment.user_id = current_user.id
```

But, if I want to auto populate `user_id` like `article_id`, how can I do?

Comment: Your associations looks a bit flawed to me. It is weird that only comments belongs to user but not article isn't it?

Comment: No, User also has_many articles i.e., article is belongs_to User

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct way of doing that

But I follow this way

```
@comment = @article.comments.build(comment_params.merge(user: current_user))
```